# Ruby on Rails, save an array to json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, haml

I am new to Ruby on Rails. I have a `Log` class which is message outputted by human (i.e. chat) and computer program (debug information). In the index page I have a table and I want to have a link to save all logs to json format. I have tried this for a long time but seems to not make any progress. Can anyone help me?

What I believe to be the right way:

In Haml, pass the array of logs as `params[:data]` to a wildcard matching route to controller. Then the controller `render json: params[:data]`.

What I have done so far:

I have the route (which doesn't seem correct)

```
get 'save_to_json/*data', to: 'logs#save_to_json', on: :collection
```

This generates

```
               GET    /logs/save_to_json/*data(.:format) logs#save_to_json
```

Note there is no name for this route.

In Haml, I have

```
%p= link_to "Save to JSON", 'logs/save_to_json'(selected)
```

where `selected` is the array of logs that I want json for. I want to pass `selected` as the match for `data` in route but this gives me an error.

In `logs_controller` I have

```
def save_to_json
    render json: params[:data]
end
```

I want to know whether passing an array back is possible and what is the correct way of doing it. Maybe there are some easier ways to just convert an array to json in Ruby but I would like to know how to do it if this is a general task.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way is to use the RABL class as that essentially will convert data objects into JSON for you

Comment: Can you suggest a general way of doing this (i.e. custom routing wildcard matching with passing variables from view to controller)?

Comment: The way I learned were from Railscasts, if you have been to that site before. Note: I am not a contributor nor employee to Railscasts but do value their resources.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
def save_to_json
  render json: params[:data]
end
```

and construct your `data` params using the array notation - appending `[]` to the parameter name

```
http://localhost:3000/logs/save_to_json?data[]=foo&data[]=bar
```

which should render

```
[ 'foo', 'bar' ]
```

I just want to say this is a strange way to do things, why not save the data in your `Log` models and then request a json representation of the data?

```
def index
  @logs = xxxx
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render json: @logs }
  end      
end
```

and then make your save link

```
%p= link_to "Save to JSON", logs_path(format: :json)
```

Comment: I want the user to be able to select which logs he wants to save (by checkbox or a filter, e.g. logs that are in a time range). That's also why I don't save `@logs` but `selected`. Then I think I need to pass the list of logs to save from the view back to the controller. Is there a better way of doing this?